# Implementing/simulating 16bit counter with 20Mhz clock and 1024 prescaler in C

Tags: c, timer, counter, atmega

I'm looking to (roughly) simulate an Atmega128's Timer/Counter1 in C
This is a 16bit counter, with a clock running at 20MHz (F_CPU). I'd like a prescale  (CLOCK_PRESCALER) of 1024.

My current implementation is the following:

```
// Simulate 16bit counter with a 16MHz clock and prescale of 1024 (as mega128)
// The counter overflows every 65 536* 1024/20M= 3.3554432s or 3355.4432 ms or 3355443.2us or 3 355 443 200 ns
UInt32 getClock(void){

    UInt32 curr_clock_time_us;
    UInt32 diff;
    UInt32 unscaled_clock;
    UInt32 scaled_clock;
    struct timespec temp;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &temp);
    curr_clock_time_us = temp.tv_nsec/1000;

    diff = curr_clock_time_us - prev_clock_time_us;

    //represents timer overflows, which happens every 4194304000 ns.
    if(diff > ((UInt32)3355443)){
        prev_clock_time_us = curr_clock_time_us; // on overflow the counter (here the  diff) should be 0 if we asked it immediately again.
        unscaled_clock = (diff % ((UInt32)3355443));
    } else {
        unscaled_clock = diff;
    }

    //Scale to count value: time
    scaled_clock = unscaled_clock * F_CPU  / CLOCK_PRESCALER * 1/1000 * 1/1000;

    return scaled_clock;
}
```

Uint32 is a typedef unsigned long.

prev_clock_time_us is initialized at board_init() as

```
    //Starts the clock by registering current time, down to microseconds
struct timespec temp;

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &temp);
prev_clock_time_us = temp.tv_nsec/1000;
```

To test this code, I continuously print it out.
What I expected or hoped to see is a clock going from 0 -> 65536 -> 0 in roughly 3.355s.

Instead, what my printouts show is the clock going from 0 -> ~20000 -> 0.
Which is odd. Just printing, for example, the curr_clock_time_us seems that that value goes from 0 -> 1.000.000 -> 0.

Looking at  reveals that "CLOCKS_PER_SEC is required to be 1 million" but I'm not sure if that is related.

So any clue what I am doing wrong? I'm unsure exactly.

Comment: Your use of `clock_gettime` indicates a POSIX platform (like Linux or OSX), and if you're doing this on a 64-bit system then your type-alias `Uint32` is misleading, as `long` usually is 64 bits then. Instead use one of the [*standard* fixed-width integers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) like `uint32_t`.

Comment: This line seems super suspicious: `scaled_clock = unscaled_clock * F_CPU  / CLOCK_PRESCALER * 1/1000 * 1/1000;` I think the odds of integer overflow are high, and things like `* 1/1000` are unclear in integer math (replace with `/1000`).

Comment: You are absolutely right! Unfortunately, I'm working on adjusting an existing code base so not my own code. I am planning on changing it in the future though (if I continue on this project), so thanks for the reminder!

Edit: Ah, didn't see your comment there! Did so, but did not change the problem. Good thing to keep in mind though, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curr_clock_time_us = tv_nsec / 1000 is the time in micro seconds and will always <= than 1.000.000 us = 1 s

you although have to use tv_sec to calculate time differences over ones second.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define F_CPU 16000000
#define CLOCK_PRESCALER 1024

using namespace std;

time_t prev_clock_time_s;
long prev_clock_time_us;

uint32_t getCounter(void){

    long diff;

    struct timespec temp;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &temp);

    diff = ((temp.tv_sec - prev_clock_time_s) * 1000000) + ((temp.tv_nsec/1000) - prev_clock_time_us);

    return (diff % 3355443l) * 65536l / 3355443l;
}

int main()
{
    struct timespec temp;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &temp);
    prev_clock_time_s = temp.tv_sec;
    prev_clock_time_us = temp.tv_nsec/1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        uint32_t cnt = getCounter();
        std::cout << "counter_value: " << cnt << " time: " << (cnt * 3.3554432 / 65536) << std::endl;
        usleep(300000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fabously, thanks. I kept it in my format but this does make sense.

As an addendum (this confused me for a second), qRayner appended the letter 'l' to the return statement, this is not the number '1'!